# Write Pandas dataframe to list of rows

Tags: python, pandas

How can i write out a pandas dataframe to lists

```
      X    Y  Z    Value 
0      18   55  1      70   
1      18   55  2      67 
2      18   57  2      75     
3      18   58  1      35  
4      19   54  2      70
```

Output to text file like

```
[
    ["X", "Y", "Z", "Value"],
    [0, 18, 55, 1, 70],  
    [1, 18, 55, 2, 67],
    [2, 18, 57, 2, 75],  
    [3, 18, 58, 1, 35],
    [4, 19, 54, 2, 70],
]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Convert data and columns separately and join by `+`:

```
L = [df.columns.tolist()] + df.reset_index().values.tolist()

[['X', 'Y', 'Z', 'Value'], 
 [0, 18, 55, 1, 70],
 [1, 18, 55, 2, 67], 
 [2, 18, 57, 2, 75], 
 [3, 18, 58, 1, 35], 
 [4, 19, 54, 2, 70]]
```

For avoid index remove [`DataFrame.reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html):

```
L1 = [df.columns.tolist()] + df.values.tolist()
print (L1)
[['X', 'Y', 'Z', 'Value'], 
 [18, 55, 1, 70], 
 [18, 55, 2, 67], 
 [18, 57, 2, 75], 
 [18, 58, 1, 35], 
 [19, 54, 2, 70]]
```

Comment: How can i remove the index from appearing in the Values list? I do not need that?

Comment: @JokerMartini - If want avoid it only remove `.reset_index()`